# Search for a code change in all branches

Tags: git

I'm looking for a commit which introduced a line of code with the word "Rental" somewhere in my project.  How can I search all branches for the commits where lines were introduced that included that phrase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git log --branches -S "Rental"
```

You can also use `--all` instead of `--branches`, which will include tags, remote branches and your first stash.

Comment: The only problem with this is it only shows you the commits that contain the change, you're still left trying to figure out which branches they're on, right?

Comment: Question says "looking for a commit", but as you indicate below you can use `git branch --contains <commit>` after that commit is identified.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for the "first time" that something is introduced, you might want to try `git bisect` instead of `.`. It will walk you through setting up the "it's not here" point and the "it's definitely here" and then plop you down on different commits (asking "is it here?") until it isolates where it is.

It's also not blindly going through the history linearly, but rather "bisecting" the tree as though you were searching a binary tree.

It's a bit slower than a whole-history grep, but more useful for generally trying to track down the "first time" of anything else; the primary use case is "when is the first time this bug could have happened."

It would then make sense to see what branches include that commit using `git branch --contains <commit>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git log -Srental --all --pretty=oneline
```